# Will 2x Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU N2840 @2.16GHz support 64bit Ubuntu18.04?

Tags: drivers, 18.04, 64-bit, cpu

I have : 2x Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU N2840 @2.16GHz .

Will it support 64bit Ubuntu18.04 ?

I have checked using `lshw -class CPU` that width is : 64bit.

But http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/ says I might require AMD64 etc as mentioned for 64bit. I want to install 64bit, but am not sure if it will work.

Other spec : 2GB RAM.

Comment: Sorry, I am still not sure if Ubuntu18.04 64bit will run or not? I have Ubuntu 16.04 32bit currently and I need to upgrade it to 64bit. :(

Comment: amd64 = 64-bit so installing a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 64-bit will work. Please note that there is no iso for Ubuntu 18.04 32-bit, only for Ubuntu 18.04 64-bit so 64-bit is the only iso that is available.

Comment: After installing Ubuntu18.04 do you think my laptop will run some decent games okayish way? What do you suggest?

Comment: As usual show some love to your hardware and you can run anything you want. If you have Minecraft try `sudo snap install minecraft`

Comment: @noob *"do you think my laptop will run some decent games"* - unfortunately many newer games will demand more power than an N2840 can offer. Older games, browser of java games will however still run. Other memory intense application will if at all perform rather sluggish. Consider  a memory upgrade to 4 GB (if that is possible) or more - it will really make much of a difference.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes but it will probably be slower than you hope. [cpubenchmark.net](https://www.cpubenchmark.net/compare/AMD-Athlon-64-X2-3800+-vs-Intel-Celeron-N2840/1511vs2388) rates that CPU at 1004. I have an Athlon 64 X2 3800+ which it rates as 958. It is in a system with 2GB of RAM running Ubuntu 18.04. It will do a few things well (fileserver, usenet, torrentz), but I'd never use it to browse the internet or play movies or anything that I wanted it to respond me in real time.

I'm also curious about what the 2x in "I have : 2x Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU N2840 @2.16GHz." Does that mean you have 2 CPUs? If so I'm curious about the motherboard, RAM, etc.

Comment: It has Intel Celeron Dual Core Processor and 2GB DDR3 RAM. For other specifications please check : https://www.gadgetsnow.com/laptops/Acer-Aspire-ES1-512-NXMRWSI002-Laptop-Celeron-Dual-Core-1st-Gen2-GB500-GBWindows-8-1